# Uri declaration fails when paramaters are not String Flutter

Tags: flutter, uri

I'm updating my code to latest Flutter/Dart package versions and I see http requests now need to be made passing a `Uri` instead of a `String`.

```
final String request =
       'https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/locations/$isoLocationDb/nearbyCities?minPopulation=150000&radius=30';
```

Of course I could just use

```
var response = await get(Uri.parse(request), headers: headers);
```

which works as expected but I wanted to construct the Uri so new code would be

```
Map<String, dynamic> parameters = {'minPopulation': 150000, 'radius': 30};

    Uri uri = Uri.https('wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com',
        '/v1/geo/locations/$isoLocationDb/nearbyCities', parameters);

    print('∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞∞  GetCityDb 1st Uri is : $uri'); // No prints

    var headers = {
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com',
      'x-rapidapi-key': apiKey,
    };

    var response = await get(uri, headers:headers);
```

but then `Uri` declaration goes wrong ( I don get it printed ) and the method returns an `int` instead of a `List<String>` (got it from my Bloc error `int is not a subtype of List<String>`.

It results that changing `parameter`'s values to String
solves the problem.

Shouldn't be supposed to accept numbers as it is a `Map<String, dynamic>`?
Doesn't `Uri` stringify those values?

Comment: "Doesn't `Uri` stringify those values?" No, it does not. [The `Uri` documentation should be better](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46251), but the documentation for the [`Uri` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/Uri/Uri.html) explains: "When `queryParameters` is used the query is built from the provided map.... A value in the map must be either a string, or an `Iterable` of strings...."

Comment: Oh I see.  I didn't see it. Cheers